# Direct or indirect reference in TypeScript 3.5

Tags: typescript, mobx-state-tree

We are using a library mobx-state-tree which include fairly complex TypeScript declarations that are hard to decipher for me.

Either way, it seems that some change happened between TS 3.4 and 3.5 that caused a strange issue.

[image]

I have prepared a minimal reproduction in a repository: https://github.com/FredyC/mobx-state-tree-ts3.5

I am aware this is probably a very specific problem that needs a deep dive. Would appreciate at least the right direction what change in TS 3.5 could be causing an issue like that.

### Update

Based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781615/902813 I tweaked the example in a repo and got a similar error. It seems like that mobx-state-tree could be abusing some bug in TS which got fixed in 3.5 and now it breaks stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be certain what is the deep cause of your problem just by a quick look of your code, but in your minimal example, TS is complaining about `get root()` method in BaseModel.ts referring itself in its return value (as for where, it might take a while to find, as `mobx-state-tree` is quite big), so you need to add a type to it by writing `get root(): TRootModel` and then your project will compile just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, that definitely helped in the right way. Unfortunately, it seems there is something wonky happening. I've expanded the example slightly to be closer a real implementation and getting a similar error in different places now.

It does work if I explicitly set the return type, but that's hardly a solution considering it was all typed correctly with TS 3.4. So I wonder if some change needs to be done in mobx-state-tree code or why is this happening.